# How to reduce complexity of 27 by replacing if/else block to something else in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, complexity-theory

I have a weather display with emojis adjusted by if/else statement, but there is a major delay evidently since the complexity is 27, how do I replace such method with a replacement that would reduce complexity?

Sort of new to front-end world, any help is much appreciated.

```
  function drawWeather( d ) {
  var celcius = Math.round(parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15);
  var fahrenheit = 
  Math.round(((parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15)*1.8)+32);
  var main_description = d.weather[0].main; 
  var description = d.weather[0].description; 

  var day_time = isDay()

  document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = d.name;

  if       ( main_description === 'Clear' && day_time == true) {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' + ' ☀️';
  } else if ( main_description === 'Clear' && day_time == false) 
  {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' + ' ';
  } else if( main_description === 'Clouds' ) {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' + ' ☁️';
  } else if( main_description === 'Drizzle' ) {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' + ' ️';
  } else if( main_description === 'Rain' ) {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' + ' ️';
  } else if( main_description === 'Thunderstorm' ) {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' + ' ⛈️';
  } else if( main_description === 'Snow' ) {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' + ' ❄️';
  } else if( main_description === 'Fog' ) {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' + ' ️';
  } else if( main_description === 'Mist' ) {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' + ' ️';
  } else if( main_description === 'Haze' ) {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' + ' ️';
  } else if( main_description === 'Tornado' ) {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' 
  + ' ️';
  } else if( main_description === 'Dust' ) {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;' 
   + ' ️';
  } else {
  document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = fahrenheit + 
  '&deg;';
  }
  }
```

Comment: Map the value to its icon; changes the massive conditional to a couple lines. Easy enough to special-case for day/night, although that could be handled somewhat-elegantly as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far to do this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Use object/Map to map dependent strings and loop through that?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Why a loop with an object? o.O

Comment: @Andreas : to make connection of `'Clear'` to ☀️, `'Clouds'` to ☁️, etc

Comment: @DaveNewton I'd personally just map based on both keys - description + time of day. Then put double entries for the things that should be the same for day/night.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov There's no _"connection"_. You only have one special case `'Clear'` + `day_time` and that's just an `if ( ... )`

Comment: @Andreas : are we still talking about turning 27 `if`'s into something reasonable?

Comment: @VLAZ Yup, that'd work too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. At least show your effort that you do work with the code but can't find a way to go
2. Post a formatted code to show your respect with the community
3. This is a topic of "DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself" in programming. You can search with that keyword and learn it.
4. The code below is what I can do but untested.

```
let data = [
    { weather: 'Clear', icon_day: '☀️', icon_night: '' },
    { weather: 'Clouds', icon: '☁️' },
    { weather: 'Drizzle', icon: '️' },
    { weather: 'Rain', icon: '️' },
    { weather: 'Thunderstorm', icon: '⛈️' },
    { weather: 'Snow', icon: '❄️' },
    { weather: 'Fog', icon: '️' },
    { weather: 'Mist', icon: '️' },
    { weather: 'Haze', icon: '️' },
    { weather: 'Tornado', icon: '️' },
    { weather: 'Dust', icon: '️' }
]

let icon = '';
data.forEach(element => {
    if (main_description === 'Clear') {
        icon = isDay() ? element.icon_day : element.icon_night
    } else if (main_description === element.weather) {
        icon = element.icon;
    }
});

document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = `${fahrenheit}&deg; ${icon}`;
```

Comment: None of the text in your answer improves the quality of your answer. 1 to 3 should (if at all) be a comment on the question. 4 doesn't explain anything.

Comment: _"...but untested"_ - Use a snippet and test it.

Comment: Why `.forEach()`? `.find()` would make more sense because it stops on the first matching element.

Comment: I can do explain and test but with such a simple example, why don't let OP do it? He's still learning, right?

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): _"Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, **but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.**"_

Comment: If he wants to know the difference in performance of `forEach`, `for`, `find`, I can spend more time but with this question, a fuller explanation is redundant. Don't you think that giving a full commented code in **each** line with this short snippet will make him lazier to learn to program? Newbies **need** to learn how to search for a document of a strange function or a new concept. Giving the fishing rod, not the fish.